# Utility to tune network card to reduce latency to its absolute minimum?

Tags: windows, networking, software-rec, latency

I'd like to tune my network card to have the absolute minimum latency when pinging a remote server.

Is there a Windows utility that allows me to change things such as MTU, ACK time, buffer length, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Speed Guide - TCP Optimizer**](http://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php) can help you do this, that site also lists a lot of other useful information.